# Работа с com-портом

Tags: delphi

Не подскажите, где можно посмотреть простой пример работы с com-портом? Также, можно ли включить и выключить светодиод у com-порта из delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот](http://virun.com.ua/info/?delphi.action&id=02003) тут компонент и описание с примерами для работы с ComPort.
простого зажигания светодиода, как с LPT  по ComPot не получиться , так как ComPort это последовательный порт, а LPT параллельный. Да и по току не выдержит COM светодиода.

Comment: Не подскажите, как можно включить и выключить светодиод у LTP-порта из delphi?

Comment: Дак вам LPT или ком нужен?
Для LPT есть неплохая библиотека `Inout32.dll`, она экспортирует 2 функции: запись в порт и чтение из порта.

Comment: Я хочу управлять внешними устройствами с помощью Delphi. Например, включить и выключить светодиоды или управлять моторчиками.

Comment: Ну все таки для управлением внешней переферией проще будет использовать LPT.
А чем вам помочь?
Я не знаю Ваших познаний в области программирования, так как задача не сложная.
[Вот статья](http://www.pcports.ru/articles/10.php) она довольно подробно описывает принцип работы с LPT c Delphi

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: Ну если вопрос решён то примите ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для зажигания светодиодов лучше всего подходит LPT порт. Для com порта без дополнительной платы ничего не выйдет. Ну разве что 1 светодиод зажечь :)

Comment: Ну почему же не выйдет? И почему один? Хотя применение для ком порта не самое лучшее.

Comment: Не подскажите, как можно включить и выключить светодиод у LTP-порта из delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться [этим](http://www.delphirus.com/modules.php?name=Pages&pa=showpage&pid=866). Про светодиод - имеется в виду как подключить к порту светодиод? Можно попробовать через банальный баластник. Если особой яркости не надо, то сойдет. Изменяя скважность импульсов можно и яркостью управлять. Учтите только амплитуду сигнала на выходе порта (-12...+12 В).

Comment: Не подскажите, как можно включить и выключить светодиод у LTP-порта из delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Все уже давно есть на DelphiKingdom:

- [Асинхронный режим чтения из Com-порта](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=723)
- [Работа с СОМ-портом в Windows](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1126)

Если коротко зарезюмировать: компорты доступны в винде как файлы с именами `\\.\COM1`, `\\.\COM2` итд. Соответственно работа с ними ведется, главным образом, WinAPI-шными средствами `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Не подскажите, как можно включить и выключить светодиод у LTP-порта из delphi?