# Создать подключение, используя GPRS-модем, подключённый к COM-порту

Tags: c++builder, c++

В книге Ч.Калверта "Borland C++ Builder" изд. DiaSoft 2005г. в главе 16 описано, как при помощи RAS-функций можно создать подключение к интернету при помощи модема, работающего по телефонной линии. 
А как можно создать подключение, если используется GPRS-модем, подключённый к COM-порту, причём инициализация модема выполняется AT-командами?
Идея такая, сначала надо при помощи AT-команд зарегистрировать модем в сети, а потом создать подключение к сети, чтобы его видел, например, браузер. Надо ли создавать "телефонную книгу", если да, то как быть с набором номера, ведь в GPRS никаких номеров дозвона нет.

Answer (score 1):

Работайте с COM портом напрямую, отправляйте ему команды AT, получаете ответы. Поиграйтесь с командами AT (подсмотрев их в гугле) через терминал подключений, попробуйте все сделать там, а потом уж перенесете.

Тема о том, как работать с COM-портами была вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41489/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-com-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC), правда для Delphi. Но полагаю, что трудностей адаптировать для Builder не возникнет.

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что с AT-командами всё нормально, но как полученное соединение зарегистрировать в Windows, как сеть?